# Running Docker on a Netbooted Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, nfs

I've recently switched to having my Raspberry Pi be netbooted instead of running off the micro SD card. I have gotten it to work, all the files were moved off the SD card and the pi boots and runs with the tftp server being run off my TrueNas server. Unfortunately I've since learned that Docker's default storage driver overlay2, does not support NFS. I have done some digging and found out you can get Docker to work, but you need to use iscsi instead of NFS. Given that I already have the Pi working on NFS is there anything I can do to have Docker work with NFS? Are any of the other storage drivers compatible/ recommended for NFS? Are there any options besides redoing this process to be iscsi instead of NFS?

Comment: Do you *have* an SD card in there and available for use? Or any form of local storage?

Comment: Not currently, but I can. Is there a way to use the SD as like a "Separate drive" for Docker?